# Python 2.7 vs 3.8 install fails with network error

Tags: python, installation, package

When I try to run the command `pip install -e`,
I am getting the following error for python38, but it is working for python27.

Can somebody please help on this.

```
command: /home/myname/virtualenvs/python38/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/myname/projectname/projectname/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/home/myname/projectname/projectname/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info
         cwd: /home/myname/projectname/projectname/
    Complete output (25 lines):
    Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/pbr/: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'pbr' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or working download links found for pbr>=1.8
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/myname/projectname/projectname/setup.py", line 33, in <module>
        setuptools.setup(
      File "/home/myname/virtualenvs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/home/myname/virtualenvs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/home/myname/virtualenvs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "/home/myname/virtualenvs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "/home/myname/virtualenvs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/home/myname/virtualenvs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/home/myname/virtualenvs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/home/myname/virtualenvs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 673, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pbr>=1.8')
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: could you please adjust the error result and explain what you are trying to install?

Comment: Did you read the error message, in particular "[Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!"

Comment: johnny , pip install -e . is a command to install all the required packages for my project which is made by my project team and when run this command in python2.7 environment it is working properly but when I do the same with python3. 8 environment it is not .

Comment: Robert , if it is network problem it should not work with python2.7 also but it is working so i  think it is not the problem with network.